# How do I filter the line with the most recent date, keeping the same structure as input?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to make a function in Scala to filter the most recent date. I want to keep it general, so whatever dataframe I input, as long as it has the column "date", will return me the most recent line of that dataframe. It's worth noting that my date column is usually defined as a string, in the format yyyy-MM-dd. I'm pretty sure that my code here is flawed, but I guess it illustrates the idea.

```
  def fixDate(table: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    table
      .withColumn("date", from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("date"), "yyyy-MM-dd"), "yyyyMMdd").cast(Integer))
      .filter(col("date")===functions.max("date"))
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on what you want to achieve. If you want to get all the columns with the maximum value by the "date" field, then from the point of view of performance, you'd better divide this action into two stages, getting the maximum value of the column, and filtering by it:

```
val maxValue = df.withColumn("eventTime", unix_timestamp(col("date"), "yyyy-MM-dd")).cast(TimestampType))
.agg(max("meventTime1")).collect()(0)(0)

df.withColumn("eventTime", unix_timestamp(col("date"), "yyyy-MM-dd")).cast(TimestampType))
.filter(col(eventTime1) === maxValue).drop("eventTime")
```

If you want any record with the maximum value, then I think the answers from this post will help you: [How to get the row from a dataframe that has the maximum value in a specific column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49600863/how-to-get-the-row-from-a-dataframe-that-has-the-maximum-value-in-a-specific-col)